# Database for single table, large amount of data, fast access

Tags: database, nosql

Our project needs to store data acquired by sensors in a process plant. There are around 50,000 inputs and average sampling rate is 10 times / second. Data is first cached in RAM then dumped to HDD every 1 second. The data must be able to be accessed real time (search / edit / delete... by ID or value or timestamp) by about 40 clients.

Data structure for storing on HDD is simple, it is just a single table and each row consists of: sensor ID (2 bytes), timestamp (4 bytes) and encoded value (4 bytes).

A calculation for writing-to-HDD speed is as follows: 50,000 * 10 * (2 + 4 + 4) bytes / second ~ 4.8 MB / second.

Which kind of storing technique on HDD should I use? SQL vs NoSQL vs Simple File?

Comment: Instead of a simple file, you might be able to use the file system and sub-directories named with the ID, timestamp, etc.

Comment: @SteveWellens - the timestamp is millisecond-precise, so there will be lots of file created, aren't there?

Comment: It sounds like there is going to a lots of _something_ created.   A solid state drive or thumb drive may help performance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need create files for each dump. You can create one file for each hour (or day) so the search /edit/delete can be much faster than one huge file.

If your only need some simple searches, i think simple files based on Steve's suggestion might be the solution you need.

SQL/NoSQL solutions for this kind of data rate exist but they will be expensive. If you want to do a lot of editing and deletion on the "active" table, it can be worse. If you need archive those data for more advanced queries, you may load them later to a db server (one another system) hourly or daily, it will be much faster and cheaper than inserting them in real time.

Comment: "If you need archive those data for more advanced queries, you may load them later to a db server (one another system) hourly or daily, it will be much faster and cheaper than inserting them in real time." ---> Even the data is loaded into a db server hourly or daily, the average data rate required doesn't change. So why do you think it can be much faster?

Comment: Database operations are more than data transmission. Bulk loading has its advantages by skipping some processes such as committing and indexing.

Comment: According to [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/317643/building-a-1-000m-row-mysql-table), by the use of Load Data InFile in MySql (the best way to load data into a DB) and with very high performance hardware (256 GB of RAM), the average speed is up to ~ 100k rows / s. Each row is about 20 bytes - long, so the rate is around 2 MB / s.

Comment: I don't have many experiences on mysql bulk loading,but I understand it's far from the best. Check sql server bcp or hp vertica copy data instead. 2mb/s is by far not the best mysql can do for you either. Again, bulk loading might not a good option for your case and you can ignore my suggestion if in doubt. Even using real time insertion, with proper coding and configuration, an entry level large database system should be able to handle 10+ mb/s i/o.